# Replace small u with single quote in vba

Tags: vba

I want to replace u' from the string using VBA. So, u'DROP_MOBILE': u'1234567890' and I need to change it as **"DROP_MOBILE": "1234567890"**

I tried with

```
strText = "u'DROP_MOBILE': u'1234567890'"
newstrTxt = Replace(strText, "u'", """")
```

it returns u"DROP_MOBILE": u"1234567890"

it only remove the single quote after u and u does not gets removed.

Comment: What seems to be problem? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with 
strText = "u'DROP_MOBILE': u'1234567890'"
newstrTxt = Replace(strText, "u'", """") 

it returns u"DROP_MOBILE": u"1234567890"

it only remove the single quote after u and u does not gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the replace, one to remove `u` and the other to replace the single quotes `'` with double `"`.

```
Const strText As String = "u'DROP_MOBILE': u'1234567890'"

Debug.Print Replace(Replace(strText, "u", ""), "'", """")

'"DROP_MOBILE": "1234567890"
```